# Can the input value be the same as a placeholder in an HTML form?

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, codeigniter

I have an HTML form that accepts a CVV number as one of the field items -

```
<label for="cvv">CVV</label>
<input type="text" placeholder="123" maxlength="3" id="cvv" name="cvv">
```

As you can see, it has a `placeholder="123"`. I'm entering the CVV number into my database as part of an array -

```
$pay = array(
    'cardno' => $cardno,
    'exp' => $this->input->post('exp'),
    'cvv' => $this->input->post('cvv'),
    'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
    'org' => $this->session->userdata['user_data']['org']
    );
$this->db->insert('payment', $pay);
```

I'm able to enter any CVV value into the database except `123` which is the same as the placeholder value. I keep getting the following error -

```
Error Number: 1366

Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'cvv' at row 1

INSERT INTO `payment` (`cardno`, `exp`, `cvv`, `name`, `org`) VALUES ('6547893210258135', '04/20', '', 'Joe Bloggs', '15')

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\ci_redesign_newdb\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

When I print the `$pay` array before inserting it into the database, with `cvv as 123`, the CVV field is empty -

```
Array ( [cardno] => 6547893210258135 [exp] => 04/20 [cvv] => [name] => Joe Bloggs [org] => 15 )
```

However, if I change the CVV value to anything else, the CVV field gets populated -

```
Array ( [cardno] => 6547893210258135 [exp] => 04/20 [cvv] => 103 [name] => Joe Bloggs [org] => 15 )
```

And since that field gets populated, I'm able to enter it into the database without any errors. What could be the reason the form isn't accepting a value that is the same as the field's placeholder, i.e., `123` in this case?

**EDIT 1**

This problem seems to be present for all input fields in the form. I only noticed it for `cvv` since I happened to enter `123` as a test. So, it looks like all the fields where the entered input value is the same as the placeholder value are not being input.

**EDIT 2 - PROBLEM SOURCE**

It looks like the problem is originating from the jQuery source file version 2.0.3. I commented out the file in my code -

```
<script src='<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js'></script>
```

and I was able to post the input values which were the same as my placeholder -

```
Array ( [cardno] => 1234567890123456 [exp] => mm/yy [cvv] => 123 [name] => Name [org] => 15 )
```

Is this something that can be solved by editing the jQuery source file? Should I be making such changes? Don't want to make changes that could cause problems elsewhere.

Comment: Are you sure you're inserting any value in the cvv? Check your validation again too. And have you tried to insert 123 through phpMyAdmin? If it works, there's something wrong in your code.

Comment: @BenJunior I'm sure I'm inserting the value 123 into cvv. Checked it multiple times on my localhost and test server. I can manually enter the value in SQLyog. There's something definitely wrong in the code, I'm sure. The php is alright since it's able to insert values other than 123. I'm thinking the placeholder is somehow causing a conflict.

Comment: Well, put placeholder to be `103` and try with both values `123` and `103`. Also be aware of `maxlength` - CVV can be 4 digit in length.

Comment: When you say you entered the place holder value into the cvv field, did you actually enter it or just leave the placeholder text that was in the field. Place holder text is not normally sent to the server so you would need to literally type 123 in the cvv input for the server to see that value.

Comment: Do you have any javascript active on that page?

Comment: @Tpojka I changed the placeholder to `103`, and tried inserting `103` and `123`. It failed to populate the field for `103` but was successful for `123`. So, it looks like whatever is the placeholder value, is not being input.

Comment: @WilliamKnauss Yes, I am typing in the cvv and clicking on a button to insert it into the database.

Comment: @AmitRay Yes, javascript is active on that page.

Comment: Do you have some JS input/form checker that maybe is comparing value of field against value of placeholder?

Comment: @Tpojka I have a jQuery Credit Card Validator but I can see nothing that's comparing the placeholder to the value being input. This problem seems to be prevalent in all the input fields. I just noticed it for cvv since I enter `123` for testing. So any field where the input value is the same as the placeholder is not being input.

Comment: Try to post without jQ included/enabled just to see if `$_POST` array has all meant elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really weird. I'm sure there is some JavaScript code or a library you are using is causing this.

A possible way around your problem is to remove/change the placeholder attribution of your inputs right before submiting it.

For example;

```
<form id="yourform" name="yourform">
 <input type="text" placeholder="123" id="cvv"/>
 <div class="button" onclick="submitForm()">Submit</div>
</form>
```

In JS;

```
function submitForm(){
   document.getElementById("cvv").placeholder = "";
    //Do it for all of your input elems.

   document.yourform.submit();
}
```

Not sure it is going to work, and I know not the actual proper way to solve it, but would do the trick.

Comment: That is a great work around. Thank you! The problem seems to be the jQuery source file that I'm using. I will edit the question to post more details.